# AngularJS: How to extra data from mixed json

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

suppose my asp.net mvc viewmodel refer multiple class say like department and employee and return json of viewmodel when action is called by angular side.

see my code.

### viewmodel and related classes

```
   public class SampleViewModel
    {

        public List<Department> Department { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Hobby> Hobby { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hobby
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

### see how i am returning json of my viewmodel class

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SampleViewModel vmSample = new SampleViewModel
    {

        Department = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department()
            {
                Name="Accounts"
            },
            new Department()
            {
                Name="Sales"
            },
            new Department()
            {
                Name="Purchase"
            }
        },

        Employee = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee()
            {
                ID=1,
                Name="john",
                Hobby=new List<Hobby>
                {
                    new Hobby()
                    {
                        Name="football"
                    },
                    new Hobby()
                    {
                        Name="hocky"
                    },
                }
            },
            new Employee()
            {
                ID=2,
                Name="ferona",
                Hobby=new List<Hobby>
                {
                    new Hobby()
                    {
                        Name="football"
                    },
                    new Hobby()
                    {
                        Name="hocky"
                    },
                }
            },
            new Employee()
            {
                ID=3,
                Name="Sam",
                Hobby=new List<Hobby>
                {
                    new Hobby()
                    {
                        Name="football"
                    },
                    new Hobby()
                    {
                        Name="hocky"
                    },
                }
            }
        }

    };

    return Json(vmSample,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

### the json which i am returning as follows

```
{
  "Department":[
    {
      "Name":"Accounts"
    },{
      "Name":"Sales"
    },{
      "Name":"Purchase"
    }
  ],
  "Employee":[
    {
      "ID":1,"Name":"john",
      "Hobby":[
        {
          "Name":"football"
        },{
          "Name":"hocky"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID":2,
      "Name":"ferona",
      "Hobby":[
        {
          "Name":"football"
        },{
          "Name":"hocky"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID":3,
      "Name":"Sam",
      "Hobby":[
        {
          "Name":"football"
        },{
          "Name":"hocky"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

now hope anyone can understand i am wrapped up department,employee and their hobby both in same json just to avoid multiple call to server side to fetch each separately.

suppose if my controller scope has two property one is employee and one is department then how could i extract only employee related json from mixed json and assign all employee json to scope.employee and same way how could i assign department json to scope.department.

please some one give me bit of angular code which show me what i am trying to achieve. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your response from server is json formatted string. you can assign them as below:

```
this.$http.get('someUrl').then(function(response) {
  $scope.employee = response.data.Employee;
  $scope.department = response.data.Department;
});
```

**[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FpS8FieDEVhNt9qz5N1U?p=preview)**

Comment: give me one jsfiddle link with my json posted here if possible

Comment: @MonojitSarkar demo added. check it please. :)

Comment: i have done a small sample following your approach and link as follows https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/0sfsnm34/  i gave you up vote too. thanks

Comment: @MonojitSarkar nice sample!